# Can I put Two AC coupling caps on PCIE bus?

Tags: decoupling-capacitor

Do you think if there is a problem when I have two AC coupling caps on PCIE bus, 220nF and 2.2uF?
Since 220nF on the daughter card and I want to put mid probe on main board.  For the transmitter from main board to daughter card, we need to place AC coupling cap before the mid probe.  so that's why I have two caps on PCIE bus.

Comment: A schematic says a thousand words. It's not clear what you are describing. What does stand out is 2.2uF sounds way too big for an AC coupling cap.

Comment: The 2.2uF with the 220nF in series results is about 200nF which is still within the PCIe spec so should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The PCIe caps should be placed near the TX origin in each direction. The mid-probe should have no caps at all, but can have probe points.

Adding more capacitance in series will reduce the capacitance, and could interfere with the low-frequency pulse sensing PCIe uses to detect the presence of a link partner.